# Wait-Process does not always work with Start-Process

Tags: powershell

```
$GAMCheck = invoke-command -ScriptBlock { C:\GAMADV-XTD3\GAM.exe version checkrc }

If ($GAMCheck) {
    $current = $GAMCheck.split(":")[19].Trim()
    $latest = $GAMCheck.split(":")[21].Trim()
    
    If ($LASTEXITCODE -eq 1) {  
        Try {
            $NeedUpGradeCode = $LASTEXITCODE
            $client = new-object System.Net.WebClient
            $client.DownloadFile("https://github.com/taers232c/GAMADV-XTD3/releases/download/v$latest/GAMadv-xtd3-$latest-windows-x86_64.msi", "C:\Temp\GAMadv-xtd3-$latest-windows-x86_64.msi")
            Start-Process -Filepath "C:\Temp\GAMadv-xtd3-$latest-windows-x86_64.msi" -ArgumentList "/passive" | Wait-Process -Timeout 75
            Remove-Item "C:\Temp\GAMadv-xtd3-$latest-windows-x86_64.msi"
  

            $GAMCheck = $null
            $GAMCheck = invoke-command -ScriptBlock { C:\GAMADV-XTD3\GAM.exe version checkrc }
            $newCurrent = $GAMCheck.split(":")[19].Trim()
    
            $resultsarray = [PSCustomObject]@{    
                CurrentVersion   = $current
                LatestVersion    = $latest
                NeedUpgradeCode  = $NeedUpGradeCode
                Upgraded         = $true
                NewCurrent       = $newCurrent
                AfterUpgradeCode = $LASTEXITCODE
            }
        }
        Catch {
            Write-Warning "Problem with site or command. Maybe go to https://github.com/taers232c/GAMADV-XTD3/releases and download the current GAM and then install GAM in C:\GAMADV-XTD3\ again"
        }
    }
}
```

lately I have been noticing that the `| Wait-process 75` above is causing an error.
If I run the command with out it everything is fine.

Is there another way to wait for the install ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To launch a process with [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) *and wait for it to exit*, use the `-Wait` switch.

Piping a `Start-Process` call to [`Wait-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/wait-process) would only work as intended if you included the `-PassThru` switch, which makes `Start-Process` - which by default produces *no* output - emit a [`System.Diagnostics.Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Diagnostics.Process) instance representing the newly launched process, on whose termination `Wait-Process` then waits.

Note that, surprisingly, the behavior of these two seemingly equivalent approaches is *not* the same, as discussed in [GitHub issue #15555](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/15555).