# Sitecore PowerShell wait for Show-ListView modal to close before proceeding

Tags: powershell, sitecore

I am writing a script which deletes users who have not logged in since a user-provided date.

I want to do the following:

1. Get date from user. (no problem here)
2. Get a list of users. (no problem here)
3. Present the user with a ListView of the potentially affected users. (no problem here)
4. Wait for the modal window to be closed before proceeding (this is where I get stuck)
5. Do some other stuff...

Steps 1-3 work fine, but when the modal window pops up, all of the code after gets executed immediately with the model window still open.

I thought Wait-ScriptSession might be my answer, but it is not doing the trick. Here's what I have right now (psuedo-code)

```
#gather users, etc
Start-ScriptSession -ScriptBlock {$listOfRemovedUsers | Show-ListView @outputProps -Property $columns} -Id "Removable Users Modal" -Interactive
Wait-ScriptSession -Id "Removable Users Modal" -Timeout 30
#do some more stuff
```

Comment: I am not sure this will help but once I asked similar and was told

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69050623/wait-process-does-not-always-work-with-start-process

Comment: and
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68727495/start-process-invoke-command-or

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using  a Wait-ScriptSession use a Confirmation Dialogue as follow just after you run the Show-ListView

```
 $listOfRemovedUsers | Show-ListView @outputProps -Property $columns
 Show-Confirm -Title "Do you want to proceed"
```

And you get a popup that will ask you if you want to proceed. on the meantime the script execution will be blocked until you click OK or Cancel
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar situation. The only solution I found was to use the "-modal" parameter: https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/appendix/common/show-listview#modal-less-than-switchparameter-greater-than

Something like this:

```
$listOfRemovedUsers | Show-ListView -Modal
$response = Show-Confirm -Title "Do you want to proceed?"
```